# Azure Cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We are using azure cloud service to publish our application. For major changes we will publish by creating and uploading packages, but for minor changes we are moving the corresponding dll to instance by taking remote machine.

We will move the dll to the folder under site root.

Our problem is that two days back we noticed whatever the changes done through incremental (i.e. by copying dll) has been lost and the folders we kept in the desktop also lost.

Comment: There is no way someone can tell you what happened on the information you have given.

Comment: @Peter - There absolutely _is_  a way to explain exactly what happened, based on given information, as statelessness is a core attribute of Azure cloud services (as Gaurav answered).

Answer (score 5):

This is expected behavior. Please note that `Azure Cloud Services` are stateless. What that means is that if for some reason Azure needs to recreate the VM that is running your code, it will use the last package file you used to create the VM.

In your case, you're manually changing the files by RDPing into these VMs and these changes are only persisted till the time that VM is alive. If the VM is decomissioned for some reason and Azure needs to create a new VM for your cloud service, your changes will be discarded.

Please see this link for more details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/09/05/how-to-modify-a-running-azure-service/.

Comment: Thanks for the information . is there any specific frequency or reason for recreating the VM so that we can try to set some alert or else we may need to do a full publish even for a small change

Comment: Unfortunately no! Other than development environment, you should not be following this practice of changing files by connecting to your VMs using RDP. Always deploy the new package files even if it is a simple change (I know it can be a huge pain!). Also think about the scenarios when you have scale your application (either manually or using auto-scale). In this case, the new instance will be deployed using the last deployed package file.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the information.It is very helpful